# getting cloud sql errors and db got restarted automatically

Tags: google-cloud-sql

These are the info logs

"2022-08-18T07:47:14.333850Z 32263817 [Note] [MY-010914] [Server] Aborted connection 32263817 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'xyz' host: '10.x.x.x' (Got an error reading communication packets)."

[Note] [MY-010914] [Server] Got packets out of order"

[Server] Got an error reading communication packets

I don't understand why I am getting this continuously on cloud sql logs also is this the reason why my db got crashed.

[image: errors]

Comment: Post the details of the logs as text. Your image is incomplete. Add the SQL server whitelist rules to your question.

Comment: I have posted the logs for example  "2022-08-18T07:47:14.333850Z 32263817 [Note] [MY-010914] [Server] Aborted connection 32263817 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'xyz' host: '10.x.x.x' (Got an error reading communication packets)." , I am getting this continously.

Comment: Also before the db crash got these  :-                                                                                                       [MY-010914] [Server] Got packets out of order"                                                                                                                                                       [Server] Got an error reading communication packets

Comment: Is your server open to the public? If it is, you are getting junk connections. Restrict Cloud SQL to only your IP address or deploy the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy.

Comment: no its not open for public , we have configured it will private ip.

Comment: Post an entire log message as text. Do not use images for text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247439/discussion-between-dante-alighieri-and-john-hanley).

Comment: Please provide the information requested in each of my comments.

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets) which might help

Comment: I have provided an answer below.Hope they were helpful

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons that could perhaps lead to the MySQL connection packet issues.According to this thread [MySQL Error Reading Communication Packets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets)

> MySQL network communication code was written under the assumption that queries are always reasonably short,and therefore can be sent to and processed by the server in one chunk, which is called a packet in MySQL terminology. The server allocates the memory for a temporary buffer to store the packet, and it requests enough to fit it entirely. This architecture requires a precaution to avoid having the server run out of memory---a cap on the size of the packet, which this option accomplishes.
>
> The code of interest in relation to this option is found in sql/net_serv.cc. Take a look at my_net_read(), then follow the call to my_real_read() and pay particular attention to net_realloc().
>
> This variable also limits the length of a result of many string functions. See sql/field.cc and sql/intem_strfunc.cc for details.

According to the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html)

- You can also get these errors if you send a query to the server that is incorrect or too large.you can increase the query limit by setting the server's max_allowed_packet variable, which has a default value of 1MB. You may also need to increase the maximum packet size on the client end. More information on setting the packet size is given in [Section C.5.2.10, “Packet too large”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html).
- An INSERT or REPLACE statement that inserts a great many rows can also cause these sorts of errors. Either one of these statements sends a single request to the server irrespective of the number of rows to be inserted; thus, you can often avoid the error by reducing the number of rows sent per INSERT or REPLACE.

Additionally you may have a look at this [link1](https://severalnines.com/blog/common-mysql-error-got-error-reading-communication-packet/) & [link2](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Connection-problem-with-MySQL-5-7-Got-an-error-reading/qaq-p/1399490)